# What cypher do I write to be able to create relationships between common value from different rows when data is stored in a table?

Tags: neo4j

[image]

In this example, I would like:

1. The 'name' to be individual nodes
2. The 'activity' to be individual nodes
3. The 'class' to be individual nodes
4. The system to automatically connect the two names to the same class node 'JUNIOR'

I essentially want the system to connect different names to nodes that they share in common.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your data is stored in a CSV file named `foo.csv` in the imports folder, and whose contents look like this:

```
id,name,activity,class
1,AB,Dance,Junior
2,CD,Biking,Junior
```

If that is true, then here is a sample Cypher statement that uses [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-import-data-from-a-csv-file) to read that file and create the corresponding nodes and relationships (using `MERGE` to avoid creating duplicates):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///foo.csv' AS row
MERGE (p:Person {name: row.name, id: row.id})
MERGE (a:Activity {name: row.activity})
MERGE (c:Class {name: row.class})
MERGE (p)-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]->(a)
MERGE (p)-[:IN_SCHOOL_YEAR]->(c)
```